# MySQL evaluation of expression changes during usage

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    @x := (600  - COUNT(h.challenge_user_historyID)) / 180 AS x,
    CASE
        WHEN (1 > 2)
            THEN 25
        ELSE
            1 + @x
    END AS priority,
    COUNT(h.challenge_user_historyID) AS n_games_actual
FROM campaigns c
LEFT JOIN challenge_user_history h
    ON (c.challengeID = h.challengeID)
GROUP BY c.campaignID
ORDER BY
    priority DESC;


+-------------+------------------+----------------+
|      x      |        priority  | n_games_actual |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| 3.000000000 | 4.11110000000000 |             60 |
| 3.222222222 | 4.11110000000000 |             20 |
| 3.333333333 | 4.11110000000000 |              0 |
| 3.111111111 | 4.11110000000000 |             40 |
| 2.777777777 | 4.11110000000000 |            100 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
```

which seems strange to me. If it is correctly obtaining the value of the `COUNT()` of `n_games_actual` in evaluating `x` (as seen in values of x in output), then why does it go wrong when doing essentially the same calculation during priority ? And how can this be rectified ?

Thanks.

Comment: value of `@elapsed_days` never changes so priority will always return 25? Or maybe I haven't understood the question properly. What is the expected output?

Comment: apologies, i've corrected the question. Thanks

Comment: You cannot be sure about the sequence of calculations due to the optimizer.

Comment: what part is the optimizer here ?

Comment: The internal optimizer creates a time / resource optimized query plan that is not necessarily in the order of your statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html : " In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:

`SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;`

However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. "

Comment: that makes sense. thank you.

Comment: There's meanwhile an answer. It's ok to accept that one. Reputation points are not everything at SO ;-)

Comment: Very gracious @Quasimodo'sclone - I saw your comment after I posted.

Comment: The query should work as expected when the calculation based on fields is done twice. @SteveE. We don't need double content on SO. If I'ld like to earn rep., I'ld do the the work forming a nice answer. You have formed a nice, easily readable answer now. Good job.

Comment: It does work, when calculated twice. Thanks both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, the behaviour of the query is unexpected, but it's not a bug.

What appears to be happening is that `@x` is not set during the query. It is only set after the calculations complete. It is set to the final row calculated, note that this may be different to the final row in the results as there is an `ORDER BY` clause which alters the order before returning the results.

It is possible to create other queries where the value of a variable is updated per row as the query executes.

The key to this is that MySQL does not make any commitment to when variables will be set within queries. The [User Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) Documentation states:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.

and

> the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

So you need to alter the query to avoid setting and reading the same variable and it should work as expected.